# Hibernate map different table with dynamic name to the same java class

Tags: hibernate, class, runtime

I have some oracle tables like table1, table 2,table n with the same structure.
If I knew before running the application how much table I have I can put some `<class>` tag with the same class name but different table name and related entity-name (duplicating the property tag mapping).
But I don't know all the table name at compile time; when the application runs it knows how many tables I have: is it possible to set the table name at query time?
All my table are like a prefix (table) plus a suffix (1,2,3,n) but I know the n-limit just at runtime.
I have to query all the tables, one by one to populate a map.

Here an example of my Bucket.hbm.xml

I'm not sure that my explaination was clear:

I have this Bucket.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.Bucket" table="BUCKETTABLE1" entity-name="Buckettable1">
        <cache usage="read-only"/>
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="value" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="VALUE" />
        </property>
    </class>
    <class name="com.Bucket" table="BUCKETTABLE2" entity-name="Buckettable2">
        <cache usage="read-only"/>
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="value" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="VALUE" />
        </property>
    </class>
    <class name="com.Bucket" table="BUCKETTABLE3" entity-name="Buckettable3">
        <cache usage="read-only"/>
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <property name="value" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="VALUE" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I want to avoid this duplication and I don't want to hard code the number of the tables handled.

Answer (score 0):

to answer the question

```
for (int i = 0; i < tablecount; i++)
{
    // %number% is a placeholder in the mapping for the table and the entity name
    configuration.add(templatemapping.replace("%number%", i);
}
```

maybe you can ease the use with

```
class Entity implements Someinterface

session.createCriteria(Someinterface.class);
```

nhibernate tries to find all mapped classes which implement the interface and does a UNION on all tables. Maybe it also does so on different entity names but same classes. then without knowing how many tables there are:

```
Entity allNtablesTogether = session.createCriteria(Someinterface.class).list();
```